# How to create a div over a part of an image in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a web application for football (soccer) matches. I have a screen with an image of football ground.

On that image I placed multiple divs for representing players. I want to add the functionality of drag drop using JQuery to add goals of each player.

For this I have to create a layer or div on the goal (as goal is already a part of the image); so I could drag a player to the goal to add goals.

See image below.

[image]

Comment: can you put it on fiddle?It will be easier to understand ur question

Comment: uh, https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ ...?

Comment: yes JQuery dragabale